# Keyboard hide sooner than view

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

The keyboard adds as a subview to the container at the bottom of the collection view controller, but when trying to hide it, it seems keyboard load sooner than increasing the size of the view (a dark viw appear just after the keyboard is going to hide).
Also, when running the project for the first time in a day, the keyboard doesn't show up until I press "command + K" then a dark view as the size of the keyboard appears above the keyboard and below the input.

```
    @objc func handleShowKeyboard(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboaradSize: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue? {
            let keyboardFram = keyboaradSize.cgRectValue
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardFram.height
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            }) { (completion) in

            }
        }
    }

    @objc func handleHideKeyboard(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboaradSize: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue? {
            let keyboardFram = keyboaradSize.cgRectValue
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                self.view.frame.origin.y += self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
                self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardFram.height
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            }) { (completion) in

            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read this key

```
UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey
```

value and use it as animation duration

---

```
guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {
    return
} 

guard let duration = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double,
    let curve =  userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? UInt else {

        return
}
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: curve)], animations: {
   ///
}) { (completed) in

}
```